# No visible @interface for 'GVRVideoView'

Tags: ios, objective-c, virtual-reality

Ok so I'm trying to implement the Google VR View into my iOS App but am getting this error with the sample project they provide. Anyone experience/overcome this? I double checked that the video it is targeting is present - don't know why it would be that anyway...

```
  // Load the sample 360 video, which is of type stereo-over-under.
  NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"congo" ofType:@"mp4"];
  [_videoView loadFromUrl:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath]
                   ofType:kGVRVideoTypeStereoOverUnder];
}
```

The specific error is:
`No visible @interface for 'GVRVideoView' delcares the selector 'loadFromUrl:ofType:'`
Thanks

Comment: In https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/reference/interface_g_v_r_video_view there is a method `loadFromUrl:` but not `loadFromUrl:ofType:`. It seems that `_videoView` is a `GVRVideoView` and it doesn't know that method.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. replacing `[_videoView loadFromUrl:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath]
                   ofType:kGVRVideoTypeStereoOverUnder];` with `[_videoView loadFromUrl:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath]];` did the job :)

Comment: Could be a sample that hasn't been updated. Since `GVRPanoramaView` has `loadImage:ofType:` (which is "quite similar).

Comment: yeah ok thanks for that :) do you know if there is somewhere I could submit this to google for inspection? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk ? That's where you got the sample, right? You can open a Ticket (Issue part: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues), or maybe check if you use the last version (of the SDK & the Sample)

Comment: good idea - will do